# Primi usi di “aria” in senso musicale

Tags: etymology

Una delle accezioni della parola “aria” è quella (citando il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/aria/)) di

> composizione melodica, sia vocale sia strumentale, in forma chiusa, costruita secondo varî ma determinati schemi strofici, che può tanto stare isolata a sé, quanto servire da elemento integratore del melodramma, dell’oratorio, della cantata, della suite e del concerto strumentale (nell’opera lirica spesso deputata all’espressione degli affetti, in contrapposizione al recitativo).

Ora, da quando si usa in italiano il termine “aria” in questo senso? Si parla per esempio di arie di Alessandro Scarlatti, e quindi un terminus ante quem sarebbe la fine del Seicento.

Comment: Secondo [The Harvard Dictionary of Music](https://books.google.es/books?hl=it&id=02rFSecPhEsC&q=aria#v=onepage&q=aria&f=true) il termine appare alla fine del XIV secolo.

Comment: Rileggendo, la mia risposta sembra corretta.

Answer (score 2):

Queasto estratto da [Treccani.it](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/aria_res-8e6050c6-8baa-11dc-8e9d-0016357eee51_%28Enciclopedia-Italiana%29/) fa riferimento all'uso del termine ***aer*** in senso musicale dal '300. L'espressione si consolida nel secolo sucessivo  e  già a metà  nel '400 viene usata con chiaro  riferimento alla musica:

> - ***Già nella terminologia musicale del '300, aer, alla latina,***  torna in senso di modus, ossia di quella divisione fondamentale dei valori di durata delle figure musicali, derivata dai metri della poesia latina, con la quale il mensuralismo franconico stabilì, verso la metà del sec. XIII, le prime sicure leggi delle lunghezze dei suoni e delle loro sottodivisioni nel tempus. Così l'adoperò, in un piccolo codice della Marciana fatto conoscere da Santorre Debenedetti, un anonimo trattatista italiano, quando, per descrivere l'andamento della musica nei madrigali nostri del '300, dice: ***volunt etiam esse de tempore perfecto et aere italico; si quis aliquando miscetur tempus aeris gallici, bonum esset.***
> - ***Verso la metà del '400, il pesarese Guglielmo Ebreo, nel suo Trattato dell'arte del ballo, prescrive che il compositore di danze "trovi il tinore, o vero il suono, il quale sia aieroso"***; e si serve anche di aiere per indicare quell'atto "di aierosa presenza ed elevato movimento", col quale il ballerino traduce nel movimento del corpo l'andamento della musica.
> - ***Che la denominazione di aria fosse poi diffusa e di moda nel '400, appare chiaro da una lettera del 1460 inviata da certo Nicolò Tedesco***, vivente in Ferrara, al marchese di Mantova, nella quale propone a maestro di canto un Giovanni Brith, abilissimo "***in cantare moderno massime arie alla veneziana"***

Comment: La fonte è la medesima citata da @DaG nella sua domanda, ma queste note riguardano la prima accezione del termine "aria" (vale a dire, appunto, il modus) e non la seconda accezione, su cui la domanda è centrata.

Comment: @Benedetta - è  da Treccani, ma non la stessa fonte. La risposta parla di ARIIA in senso musicale come di chiede nella domanda.!!!!!

Comment: se leggi l'inizio della definizione da cui hai estratto la tua risposta, vedrai che ci sono due accezioni, entrambe musicali ed entrambe ancora in uso, della parola "aria": una riguarda "come" è un suono, una melodia, una composizione; un'altra definisce una precisa forma musicale. Su questa seconda accezione è la domanda.

Comment: @Benedetta - la domanda è di carattere etimologico. Sui primi usi del termine.

Answer (score 1):

Le prime attestazioni di "aria" nel senso di "melodia" sono effettivamente, secondo il [*Dizionario storico dell'italiano antico*](http://tlio.ovi.cnr.it/voci/003691.htm) 
del Tesoro della Lingua Italiana delle Origini (TLIO), del Trecento:

> [1] ? Anonimo Genovese (ed. Contini), a. 1311, 5.17, pag. 722: Se in lor se tem[e] spina / o un poco d'asperor, / la fin mena en gram dozor; / ma in oreja asenina / sona inderno l'**eira** fina, / ni ge prende alcun amor... || Interpretano così sia Contini che Cocito, *Anon. gen.*, p. 678 e Nicolas, *Anon. gen.*, p. 558: è però possibile si tratti di un'occorrenza di **1.8.** 
>   [2] Nicolò de' Rossi, *Rime*, XIV pi.di. (tosc.-ven.), son. 310.10, pag. 198: Cherendo Amor perfetta melodia; / CO. Cognobbe il suave **ayre** di custuy...

Da notare che la interpretazione della prima occorrenza è dubbiosa: nel dizionario si afferma che questa "eira" si potrebbe anche intendere come "massa d'aria in movimento".

Tuttavia, questo non è il significato su cui si chiede nella domanda. Secondo il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000663.jpg), la prima attestazione di "aria" con questo senso

> Il componimento in versi che viene cantato 
>   su una data aria

si è riscontrata su una commedia dell'inizio del Seicento di Michelangelo Buonarroti  il  Giovane (Firenze, 1568 - 1646):

> Scherzano,  saltano,  /  e fanno  maschere  /  cantano,  suonano  /  di  più  sorte  arie.